# LADW — The condition that ensures a real matrix $A$ to have real diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

In chapter 4 of Sergei Treil's [Linear Algebra Done Wrong](https://www.math.brown.edu/streil/papers/LADW/LADW.html) (LADW), the author first introduce the theorem that an operator $A: V \to V$ is diagonalizable iff for each eigenvalue $\lambda $, the geometric multiplicity coincides with its algebraic multiplicity. He then stated the following theorem as a corollary of the above theorem, which I dont see how they are correlated: $A$ real $n \times n$ matrix $A$ admits a real factorization (i.e., representation $A = S D S^{-1}$ where $S$ and $D$ are real matrices, $D$ is diagonal, and $S$ is invertible) if and only if it admits complex factorization and all eigenvalues of $A$ are real.

Comment: Please don't use images to convey information not otherwise present in the post. [Here is the exp,anation of why you shouldn't](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Reminder appreciated, changed.

Comment: I believe if you say "geometric multiplicity coincides with algebraic multiplicity" in your own favourite words or symbols the questions will answer itself. At the moment we see no attempt form your side or an indication what exactly the question is.